# How to get to the next line?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following simpleform:

```
<f:SimpleForm title="Address" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" columnsM="2">
    <f:content>
        <Label text="Customer">
        </Label>
        <Input>
            <layoutData>
                <l:GridData span="XL4 L4 M12 S12"/>
            </layoutData>
        </Input>
        <Label text="PO reference">
            <layoutData>
                <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M12 S12"/>
            </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Input>
            <layoutData>
                <l:GridData span="XL4 L4 M12 S12"/>
            </layoutData>
        </Input>
        <Label text="PO date">
            <layoutData>
                <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M12 S12"/>
            </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Input>
        </Input>
    </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

it appears as:

[image]

How to move the label **PO date** to the next line?

Answer (score 0):

```
<f:SimpleForm title="Address" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" columnsM="2">
    <f:content>
        <Label text="Customer">
        </Label>
        <Input>
        <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL4 L4 M12 S12" />
        </layoutData>
        </Input>
        <Label text="PO reference">
            <layoutData>
                <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M12 S12" />
            </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Input>
        <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL4 L4 M12 S12" />
        </layoutData>
        </Input>
        <Label text="PO date">
        </Label>
        <Input>
        <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL1 L9 M12 S12" />
        </layoutData>
        </Input>
    </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

The above code will let you align it properly.